# Getting error when updating ADT pugin" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject"

Tags: android, android-emulator, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

here is the error i was getting   ......
   i tried like properties-Libraries changed jar file into separate folder Libs also..

```
 04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.emigos.ontime.OntimeGps5Activity.Login(OntimeGps5Activity.java:174)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.emigos.ontime.OntimeGps5Activity$1.onClick(OntimeGps5Activity.java:80)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    04-19 15:02:58.419: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new folder "libs" in the project and copy all the External Jar file files in this folder.then Right Click on Project -> Properties->Java Build Path->Here Change the Path of Jar files to "Libs" folder and remove the path of extrenal jar files that you have given from computer path.After That it will Work.

Note:if there is already folder "lib" in your project then only change the folder name "lib" to "libs".
If you are not getting my point then check this site:

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/

Name of folder Should be "libs" not "Libs"